# Prometheus check if namespace missing quota

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

How can I check if some namespace is missing quota?

I expected the `absent()` function to return 1 when something doesn't exist and 0 when something exists.
So I tried to do the next query:

```yaml
absent(kube_namespace_labels) * on(namespace) group(kube_resourcequota) by(namespace)
```

But Prometheus returned `Empty query result`.

My final goal is to alert if some namespace is missing quota, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide more information about your current setup - which Kubernetes version are you using, which solution did you use to setup a cluster (kubeadm or some cloud provider solution etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different query instead to have all namespaces where `resourcequota` is missing:

```
count by (namespace)(kube_namespace_labels) unless sum by (namespace)(kube_resourcequota)
```